# Tabbing out of the Unity search box

Tags: unity, search

When I type something into the Unity search box, I have to press the down arrow twice to get to the results area.  Where does the first press take the focus, and is there a way to change the config so that only one press of the arrow key is required to get to the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first press focuses on the title. It's something weird because you can't do anything with the title of the part the files are visible.
Tip: you can press ENTER if you want to choose the first item, the search found.

Comment: It's not just something weird.  If you search for something that shows up in multiple lenses and you want to get to say, the third lens, it's down-tab-tab-down instead of down-down-down-down-down-down(and that number of downs assumes they're all single row lense views)